# I got a error while packaging my kivy application into android apk using buildozer

Tags: android, kivy, kivy-language, buildozer

while packaging the application it returns like this? How can i resolve this error?

## Package the application

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/ranjuu/.local/bin/buildozer", line 8, in

```
sys.exit(main())
```

File "/home/ranjuu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main

```
Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
```

File "/home/ranjuu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/**init**.py", line 1071, in run_command

```
self.target.run_commands(args)
```

File "/home/ranjuu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 92, in run_commands

```
func(args)
```

File "/home/ranjuu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 104, in cmd_debug

```
self.buildozer.build()
```

File "/home/ranjuu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/**init**.py", line 214, in build

```
self.target.build_package()
```

File "/home/ranjuu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 990, in build_package

```
dist_dir = self.get_dist_dir(dist_name, arch)
```

File "/home/ranjuu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 816, in get_dist_dir

```
matching_dirs = glob.glob(join(self._build_dir, 'dist', '{}*'.format(dist_name)))
```

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'glob'

Comment: Is your buildozer up to date? It looks like this is a bug that was fixed some time ago.

Comment: yeah! i installed just now.